# Python 3.8.5 installed on MacOS but python --version returns 2.7.16 -- How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

The following is what I see in my terminal (MacOS). I've installed python and it tells me that 3.8.5 is already installed, but when I ask the terminal what version I have, it gives me something different. How do I fix this? Or what am I doing wrong?

```
Warning: python@3.8 3.8.5 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.8.5, run `brew reinstall python@3.8`
user ~ % python --version   
Python 2.7.16
user ~ %
```

Comment: Try just using `python3` as your command

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You can add `export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin:$PATH"` to your .bashrc

Comment: run `which python`, you can get the actual path of your python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `python3 --version`. It will return the answer you are expecting.